# How to create a function that accepts as an argument an n- dimensional vector and will return the vector (x1,x2^2,..xn^n) in R

Tags: r, vector, n-dimensional

How can I create a function that accepts as an argument an n- dimensional vector that will return `(x1, x2^2, ..., xn^n)` in R.

Comment: Welcome! To get good help fast on this site, it would be best if you edited your question to provide some sample data, some sample code, and an example of your desired output. Good luck!

Comment: `f <- function(x) x^seq_along(x)` defines such a function, but what do you mean by "as well as the numbers from 1 to 7"? That is just `1:7`. Surely you don't want a function on vectors which for no apparent reason returns `1:7` as well.

Comment: so what i meant about the numbers from 1 to 7, was for each number separetively the vector to give a number, f.e 1^1 , 2^2, 3^3 etc

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this? An extension of @JohnColeman's comment. This will use `cbind` to make a 2-dimensional matrix that contains both the n-dimensional input vector and the resulting product.

```
examplefun <- function(x) {
  cbind(seq_along(x), x^seq_along(x))
}

# test function
examplefun(1:7)

#     [,1]   [,2]
# [1,]    1      1
# [2,]    2      4
# [3,]    3     27
# [4,]    4    256
# [5,]    5   3125
# [6,]    6  46656
# [7,]    7 823543
```

If you just want the product:

```
examplefun <- function(x) {
  x^seq_along(x)
}
example fun(1:7)
# [1]      1      4     27    256   3125  46656 823543
```

Comment: 0



no, our prof of statistics doesnt want a matrix, he wants the vector to give us a result of xn^n. For instance, 2^2,3^3,4^4 etc

Comment: See edit - is this what you want? This is the function in the comment on your question.

Comment: Great! If this answers your question please click the checkmark to close this question out and clean up the site (so folks know this is answered and can spend their time helping others). Again, welcome to SO!